# Ajax file upload with very large text

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce, liferay

I am using tinyMCE editor in our Portal, where user can create his/her mail body. For this we have created a form and submitting that form with Ajax. Also we are providing users to attach documents with his/her mail body.

First I am providing two form submit with ajax, first one is for file and second one is for editor value:

**Sending File:**

```
var formData = new FormData($("#<portlet:namespace />interviewScheduleForm")[0]);
 jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url:'<%=insertPresentCandidateURL.toString()%>',                
     data: formData,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     async: false,
     success: function(data){
     $('#<portlet:namespace />interviewVenue').val("");
        bootbox.alert('Interview scheduled successfully');
     },
     error:function(){
         bootbox.alert('Error in Scheduling Interview');
     }
});
```

**Sending Editor Value:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',  
    url:'<%=insertPresentCandidateURL.toString()%>',
    data: $("#<portlet:namespace />interviewScheduleForm").serialize(),
    form: {
        id: '<portlet:namespace />interviewScheduleForm',
        upload: true
     },
     async: false,               
     success: function(data){
     $('#<portlet:namespace />interviewVenue').val("");
          bootbox.alert('Interview scheduled successfully');
     },
     error:function(data){
          bootbox.alert('Error in Scheduling Interview');
     }                 
});
```

The problem I am facing I can use only one of them, but I need to use both the functionality. Specially when users are pasting image in the editor I am getting a very big base64 string which cant be send to server by using the first code. While when I am using second code I am able to send the entire editor value to server but not able to send file to server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Andy -

I don't believe that you need to deal with writing code to upload images that are pasted into TinyMCE.  As documented here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

...if you configure TinyMCE 4.2+ the correct way it will handle the upload of images when they are pasted into the editor.  Your application code simply needs to deal with how to submit the form (and editor HTML) when its time to save the entire form.  TinyMCE has code as a part of the editor that will post the images to an endpoint of your choosing based on how you configure TinyMCE.  The actual task of doing the POST becomes one for TinyMCE.

Comment: @Micheal thanks for your reply. I have followed your link. One thing I am not getting that how to call that function. I want to call that function on my form sybmit. https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/#rollingyourownimagehandler

Comment: @Andy  - Please see the portion of that page titled **Using uploadImages and then posting a form.**  You can call uploadImages manually whenever you need it.  Please note that its an Async API.